# ERROR:gpu_init.cc(481)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is | using kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to create one new topic using the following command using kafka-topics.sh available inside bin directory.

I have tested this command:
C:\kafka\bin>.\kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:9092 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 5 --topic connect-test

I have got this error in cmd on windows 10.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DICvg.png)

Comment: Kafka has nothing to do with your GPU, and windows cmd doesn't run sh scripts... Plus your image doesn't show the actual command being ran, and you need to bootstrap server, **not** Zookeeper as the documentation says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you're seeing has nothing to do with Kafka. Kafka has no `.cc` files, nor need your GPU. I'm guessing you read over the other errors, such as Zookeeper flag no longer existing, for example, or that the `.sh` file isn't executable

Try this

`C:\kafka\bin> .\windows\kafka-topics.bat --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 5 --topic connect-test`